# react router dom Aw snap error in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react js and whenever I install react-router-dom it gives me "Aw snap error".
If I remove react router then it works but then navigation bar error comes. What to do????

Comment: Can you share the code and the full error trace? If possible you can also create a Sandbox link which helps in debugging faster

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a question, try to bring a minimum information. We are missing an error screenshot and your code.